# Xcode 11.3 not opening projects

Tags: xcode, xcode11.3

Xcode is refusing to open any projects, every time a project is opened the spinning wheel starts and Xcode freezes and has to be force quit. On a rare occasion the project might open after a minute or two.

I have undertaken many things to rectify this, some more drastic than others:

1. Removed all derived data.
2. Removed all of the `/Library/Developer` folder.
3. Fresh install of Xcode
4. Fresh install of MacOS, removing all Beta breadcrumbs (this was ok with a new project, as soon as I opened an older one, back to square one)
5. All the above again

There are many threads about issues with Xcode, but none that has a reputable fix; really want to get this nailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigations, some release notes were found for Xcode 8.2.1 running on macOS Sierra:

> Known Issues
>
> - When an Xcode project is stored in iCloud Drive, Xcode does not
>     automatically detect iCloud Drive sync conflicts for projects or for
>     files involved in the build. Note that the Documents and Desktop
>     folders can be stored in iCloud Drive on macOS 10.12. (18161353)
> - Opening Xcode projects and workspaces stored in iCloud Drive, or
>     changing source control branches for an open workspace or project
>     stored in iCloud Drive, may sometimes cause Xcode to hang. Note that
>     in macOS 10.12, your Documents and Desktop folders may optionally be
>     iCloud Drive locations. (28212905)

There seems to be a similar issue with Xcode 11 running on macOS Catalina.

So to solve the problem above, move any of your projects away from a location that is sync'd with your iCloud Drive, so not on the Desktop or in your Documents (if you have this activated)

I have tested this and all is super fast and back to normal.

Comment: Hope you didn’t spend ages like me to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I had this issue also as my iCloud was full.
Moving into *not syncing* directory worked.
Be aware that moving into Dropbox syncing folder might not work (I don't believe dropbox was eraising already my files uploaded to the cloud, it didn't work straight after I tried moving the folder there)

This is a terrible thing. I literally reinstall everything (operating system update, then super time consuming Xcode 13.4.1 update (about one full day, then command tools, then cmake and what not) to find out that the sudden thing which stopped recognising one of my included libraries then didn't recognise stdio.h alternating between compiling command line application but non compiling xcode from same code, and not working application in any environment..